# How to build F# type fulfilling business rules?

Tags: c#, f#, domain-driven-design, option-type

I´m trying to build a type in F#, where when I get an object of that type I can be sure it´s in a valid state.
The type is called `JobId` and it just holds a `Guid`.
The business rule is: It must be a Guid - but no empty Guid.
I´ve already implemented the type in C# but now I would like to port it to a F# class library.

That´s the C# type:

```cs
public sealed class JobId
{
    public string Value { get; }

    private JobId(string value)
        => Value = value;

    public static JobId Create()
        => new JobId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));

    public static Option<JobId> Create(Guid id)
        => id == Guid.Empty
        ? None
        : Some(new JobId(id.ToString("N"));

    public static Option<JobId> Create(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            var guid = new Guid(id);
            return Create(guid);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return None;
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I build that in F#? Thanks!

**Update 1:**
I tried to implement it as discriminated union type like this:

```ml
type JobId =
    | JobId of string
```

But the problem is, that I can´t define any business rules with that approach.
So the final question is: How to ensure that the `string` in `JobId` ist in a 
certain format?

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: you are right - I updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discriminated unions and F# records keep the internal representation public, so this only works in cases where all values of the internal representation are valid. If you need to define a primitive type that does some checks, then you need a type that hides its internals. In this particular case, I would just use a pretty much direct F# equivalent of your C# code:

```
type JobId private (id:string) = 
  member x.Value = id 
  static member Create() =
    JobId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))

  static member Create(id:Guid) =
    if id = Guid.Empty then None
    else Some(new JobId(id.ToString("N")))

  static member Create(id:string) =
    try JobId.Create(Guid(id))
    with :? FormatException -> None
```

Note that there are two cases that you want to protect against - one is `string` value that's not actually a `Guid` and the other is an empty `Guid`. You can use the type system to protect against the first case - just create a DU where the value is `Guid` rather than `string`!

```
type JobId = 
  | JobId of Guid
```

Alas, there is no way of ensuring that this guid is not empty. However, a nicer solution than the above might be to define `NonEmptyGuid` (using a class like above) that represents only non-empty guids. Then your domain model could be:

```
type JobId = 
  | JobId of NonEmptyGuid
```

This would be especially nice if you were using `NonEmptyGuid` elsewhere in your project.

Comment: The problem with using a class is that you lose meaningful equality and comparison unless you add overrides. This means you can't do things like `Seq.groupBy (fun j -> j.JobId)`. If you use a DU instead of a class this will work. I'll add another answer.

Answer (score 5):

I've adapted Tomas' answer to use a DU instead of a class to preserve proper equality and comparison, allowing `JobId` to work as expected as a grouping key, for example.

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module JobId =
    open System
    type JobId = private JobId of string with
        static member Create() = JobId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))

        static member Create(id:Guid) =
            if id = Guid.Empty then None
            else Some(JobId(id.ToString("N")))

        static member Create(id:string) =
            try JobId.Create(Guid(id))
            with :? FormatException -> None
```

You have to put the type inside a module and then you can't access the DU constructor directly outside of that module:

```
JobId.Create (System.Guid.NewGuid()) // Some (JobId "1715d4ae776d441da357f0efb330be43")
JobId.Create System.Guid.Empty // None
JobId System.Guid.Empty // Compile error
```

Comment: But here I can´t access the value directly from c#.

Comment: I solved it by adding an extension method ```[<Extension>]
        static member GetValue(jobId : JobId) : string =
            match jobId with
            | JobId.JobId id -> id```