# How to compare equality of f# discriminated union instances?

Tags: c#, functional-programming, f#, discriminated-union

A month ago I asked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58974451/how-to-build-f-type-fulfilling-business-rules) about how to fulfill business rules with F# types.

The given answer worked well for me but when working with the type I struggled by comparing two instances of that type.

Here´s the implementation again:

```ml
    [<AutoOpen>]
    module JobId =
        open System
        type JobId = private JobId of string with
            static member Create() = JobId(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))

            static member Create(id:Guid) =
                if id = Guid.Empty then None
                else Some(JobId(id.ToString("N")))

            static member Create(id:string) =
                try JobId.Create(Guid(id))
                with :? FormatException -> None

        [<Extension>]
        type Extensions =
            [<Extension>]
            static member GetValue(jobId : JobId) : string =
                match jobId with
                | JobId.JobId id -> id
```

Because it´s used as an identifier I always have to compare two instances.
*code in C#*

```cs
IEnumerable<JobId> jobIds = await GetAllJobids();
JobId selectedJobId = GetSelectedJobId();

// that´s what I would like to do
if (jobIds.Any(id => id == selectedJobId))
{
    ...
}

// now I always have to compare the strings
if (jobIds.Any(id => id.GetValue() == selectedJobId.GetValue()))
{
    ...
}
```

I tried to override `==` operators but i couldn´t do it because the internal value is not just a simple field.
Is it possible to get to my wanted behavior?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**F# unions** are .NET sealed classes with implemented structural compare by default, but they don't overrite the '==' operators.

[Check the representation of the F# classes in C#](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA2gHgIIFcAuB7A8gA4CmAdgHwC6AsAFAAEj9AtrjJsMfQFK4BGASRj0AvHSYT6uEqXoBlAJ4RsxZuMmNsCkj35DR9QgCcAlgDcAhit2DhuMPWWnSAc3oB3E9gAW6jROUrEwBjFlU+YiN6AGEjYitiAAoASgNeW0SAcUwTGAA6ADlid2zclLyAFVw5bGcXRIAiAobk5Lo/f0ZA7BCw5gio2PiVRNyQUphUsQZO/xMHXIMJvIBRZkIteh8yegLcUmIO2aZiYAguOVxmJPShUfyqmrrG5ta22iP/bt7r/siYuIJe4gJwmVxTT7HWoKGxCPJDIETe6tSGzTw+eggAD89AAYrgjMwrCsAB7BYgbEz7egAWnIu32xCAA==). You can see how the `.Equal` method is implemented.

What you can do is

```
if (jobIds.Any(id => id.Equals(selectedJobId))) {}
```